# Why flutter AppBar's automaticallyImplyLeading attribute has no effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

In main.dart file, I set appBar Theme as follows.

```
AppBarTheme(
  color: AppColors.colorWhite,
  elevation: 0,
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: AppColors.colorBlack
  ),
  centerTitle: false,
),
```

And then, the result of this appBarTheme is shown as following image.
[image]

But, some pages show a back button and some pages do not.

Showing a back button page's code is this.

```
return AppBar(
  title: KoreanText(
  TextValues.myPageAppBarText,
    style: TextStyle().pageTitle,
  ),
);
```

And, not showing page's code is this.

```
return AppBar(
  title: KoreanText(
    controller.formatCurrentDate(),
    style: TextStyle().pageTitle,
  ),
  actions: [
    _buildAppBarActions(),
  ],
);
```

In addition, the automaticallyImplyLeading attribute in all Screen's AppBar did not work at all.

Could you tell me which part of code is wrong in mine...?

---

Edit 1

I am using GetX Library for state management.

And, only bottom navigation's child screen does not have a back button.

A parent page with bottom navigation bar is a main page, child one is a home page.

The main page and home page is not a relation of child routing, but the main page has a home page inside it.

In upper case, the home page's back button is not showing.

Comment: Can you include the widgets how you are navigating between routes

Comment: Oh as your comments, there is a role between non-back button page and visible-back button page! In back button visible page, it is routed by Get.toNamed~~. But, non-back button page is not routed. It is bottom navigation's paging view - a main page has non-back button page inside it. Then, how should I solve this problem...?

Comment: are you using getx? if so consider including `flutter_getx` tag

Comment: Uh my miss.. sorry im including now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back button is not showing when navigating using bottom navigation bar, because it doesn't push new screens on your navigation stack contrary to when using `Get.to()` or `Get.toNamed()` or `Navigator.push()`. The back icon/button is only implied when there's more than one item on your navigation stack.

Comment: Oh that's true... in my bottom navigation screen, it is a root page in page tree. So, they don't have any page to return. Thank you!